# Can't retrieve record from API in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `retrieve` the following error is displayed:

> Wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)

One person here tried to help me but I think I'm being very inconvenient with my questions, it's because I really can't solve it.
I just need this to close this problem.

```
class Crud
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1'

  def create 
    nome    = Faker::Name.first_name
    salario = Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 4, r_digits: 2)
    idade   = Faker::Number.number(digits: 2)
    #note, you should pass body as JSON string
    body = { name: nome, salary: salario, age: idade }.to_json

    headers = {
      'Accept' => 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    }

    self.class.post('/create', body: body, headers: headers) 
  end

  def retrieve(id)
    self.class.get("/employee/#{ id }")
  end 
end
```

I'm trying to use it in specs

```
Consult employee Quando("é enviada a requisição para consultar o empregado") do 
  _manter_user.create 
  expect(_manter_user.create.code).to eq (200) 
  puts _manter_user.create.body 
end

Então("posso visualizar as informações retornadas") do 
  expect(@manter_user.retrieve.code).to eq (200) 
  puts _manter_user.create.body 
end
```

Comment: Please give your question a title that indicates the content of your question. Your current title is not useful.

Comment: If you want help you need to post the exact command or line of code that is throwing the error

Comment: What do you mean by 'when you run it'?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're calling `something.retrieve` without supplying the ID of what you want to retrieve

Comment: Please post the full error message including the full stack trace.

Comment: Id is an internal field, see this request!. Even if I pass a fixed value the query returns with error..  http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/1.  If I pass the fixed value I will have the same error!!     def retrieve(id)
  self.class.get("/employees/#{"147606"}")
end    See that!!   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
      ./features/pages/Empregados.rb:26:in `retrieve'

Comment: I created a class CRUD  and from this class, II create a request and then need to get the id of this request automatically through a query.   #Consult employee
Quando("é enviada a requisição para consultar o empregado") do
  _manter_user.create
  expect(_manter_user.create.code).to eq (200)
   puts _manter_user.create.body
   end                                                                                
   
Então("posso visualizar as informações retornadas") do 
  expect(@manter_user.retrieve.code).to eq (200) 
  puts _manter_user.create.body

Comment: Good work, @Vasilisa!

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland! Really appreciate your compliment

Answer (score 3):

Problem is in multiple call to `create`, you need to store result in a variable. Also you need to retrieve instance right after creation - order of specs can change and you can get in situation when you try to retrieve before creation

```
Some spanish? text goes here do 
  created = manter_user.create 
  expect(created.code).to eq (200) 
  puts created.body 

  id = JSON.parse(created)['id']
  retrieved = manter_user.retrieve(id)

  expect(retrieved.code).to eq (200)
  puts retrieved.body
end
```

Comment: @saulik I can't reproduce, your code works for me. One more time - you've created 4 employees in the code from comment - do you really want it? If no, use manter_user.create only once and store the result in variable

Comment: @saulik thank you :) If someday you'll be in Siberia - welcome! :)

Comment: @saulik you should use `id` the same way as in `retrieve` and pass update parameters in `body`, like in `create`

Comment: sorry, but as I pass the field I want to update? .. Sorry for the simple questions but I am starting now in Ruby.                                                                
  def update(id)
  self.class.put("/update/#{ id }")
end  my code: response = manter_user.create
expect(response.code).to eq (200)
puts response.body
id = JSON.parse(@response.body['name'])                                                                         puts manter_user.update(nome)                                                                       
puts manter_user.update(id)

Comment: I want to upgrade from gem faker name or gem fake.                                         
  def create 
  nome    = Faker::Name.first_name
  salario  = Faker::Number.decimal(l_digits: 4, r_digits: 2)
  idade   = Faker::Number.number(digits: 2)
  body = {name: nome, salary: salario, age: idade }.to_json